# Search within column or rectangle

Tags: search, region, isearch, rectangle, column

Is there a simple way to search within the current column or within a rectangle?

I am navigating a CSV file and would like to find the value "10" in a particular column.  Searching the entire file is unproductive.  However, it is easy to select the column with a rectangle.

I don't see any commands to search within a rectangle or to narrow to a rectangle.  The best I've been able to come up with is to copy the column and paste it into a scratch buffer and then search.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus). As far as I know, this is the only library that offers this possibility.

1. Set or bind option **`isearchp-restrict-to-region-flag`** to non-`nil`. This means that when the region is active and you start isearching the search will be limited to the region.
2. Select the text between the upper-left and lower-right corners of the column you want to search as the active region.

   You might want to use `C-x C-x` (to `exchange-point-and-mark`), depending on which end the cursor is at and which direction you want to search.
3. Make the region rectangular using **`C-x SPC`** (command `rectangle-mark-mode`.
4. Start isearching (regexp or literal-string search).

If option **`isearchp-deactivate-region-flag`** is non-`nil` then the region is automatically deactivated when you start searching, so you can better see the search space.

(You can use **`C-x n`** (command `isearchp-toggle-region-restriction`) and **`C-SPC C-SPC`** (command `isearchp-toggle-region-deactivation`) during search to toggle `isearchp-restrict-to-region-flag` and `isearchp-deactivate-region-flag`, respectively, but in each case the new value takes effect only when the current search is exited.)

---

If you use also library [Mode-Line Position](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLinePosition) then not only can you restrict Isearch to the active region but you can keep that restriction when you invoke a query-replacement command from Isearch (e.g. `M-%` from Isearch, to use `query-replace`).

The main job of that library is to show information about the active region in the mode line. And whenever you invoke a replacement command or Isearch for the active region, that region information is highlighted specially.